# Is it posible use Ajax.BeginForm to call an api on other domain?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-ajax

If i have an api and his method in the same domain. I can do something like that and it obviously works.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ApiMethod", "ApiControllerName"))
{
     ... Forms elements
}
```

Is there a way specify the domain?

ps: I don't want to use jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Ajax_AjaxExtensions_BeginForm_System_Web_Mvc_AjaxHelper_System_Web_Mvc_Ajax_AjaxOptions_), you can use the `BeginForm(AjaxHelper, AjaxOptions)` overload. Then looking at the [AjaxOptions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), that class has a `Url` property that you should be able to set.